# Recurrent fsck /dev/sda1 error - should I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, boot-repair, fsck, data-corruption

Last week I booted Ubuntu 20.04 but I got the error `initframfs: /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors`. I fixed it by manually entering `fsck /dev/sda1` but today I got the same problem.

Shall I re-install the whole Ubuntu (losing all the programs I installed) or is there a more Linux-style long-term solution?

Thank you

Comment: A single disk with corruption in my opinion is not a concern; power surge (what surge protection/filter are you using?  did a high-power device like a fridge/aircon nearby get turned on causing drop/spike in power during the session etc), however it it occurs many times that is a symptom of a problem (usually hardware related).

Comment: Also note you mention Ubuntu 20 in the title (implying a *snap* only system like Ubuntu Core 20) but then mention Ubuntu 20.04 (a *deb* based product). Ubuntu has different products using the *yy* format to the *yy.mm* format so be precise... With you mixing up different products, it may also be your lack of precision/attention-to-detail that caused the issue.

Comment: If you have recurring corrupt file system errors, this usually indicates a possibility of drive failure.  If you are trying to run `fsck` while booted it won't work, run `fsck` from the LiveUSB / installer environment, not from the system while it's running (which is dangerous and you *can't* repair the FS errors while the device is in use).

Comment: Edit your question and show me the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This window is scrollable, so it may take two screenshots. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. When you ran `fsck`, were you booted to a Ubuntu Live USB/DVD? Also show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema sorry for the delay. I ran the command, Ub. fixed the broken file. So far no other booting problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Gigiux I don't know what "Ub" means. Did you do all the parts of my answer? If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema for Ub. I meant ubuntu. Yes I did run your answer, so far mo other problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fsck**

Let's first check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**NCQ**

Your disk is getting NCQ errors, and excessive READ errors.

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**Bad Block**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: thank you. I need to find the ubuntu live usb... It is Ub. 20.04 and there might have been the washing machine active yesterday but not last week and I got the same problem today. I got the snapshot of disks: https://u.cubeupload.com/gigux/disks.png and the output from grep -i FPDMA: https://u.cubeupload.com/gigux/Screenshotfrom202105.png

Comment: @Gigiux Thanks for the info. However, the first image isn't of the **SMART Data & Tests** data window. Pull it down from the "hamburger" (3 dots) icon, then find the data window. Also, I can see that your disk is having NCQ errors. Let's redo the second command to get more data... do `grep -i -B5 -A5 FPDMA /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: thanks. the SMART Data & Tests is https://u.cubeupload.com/gigux/638Screenshotfrom202105.png but `grep...` gives nothing

Comment: @Gigiux Thanks for the updated data. My last grep command was incorrect, and should have probably been `grep -i FPDMA -B5 -A5 /var/log/syslog` or `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog -B5 -A5`. Anyway, I updated my answer. Please do BOTH the fsck and NCQ portions, then bad block the disk. Report back.

Comment: I finally found the live USB. The output from `sudo fdisk -l` is: https://u.cubeupload.com/gigux/980Screenshotfrom202105.png -- I imagine the disk with the files system is the one with EFI FAT files (/dev/sdb2). So should the command be: `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb2`?

Comment: @Gigiux No. You should use /dev/sda1, as I call out in my answer. On a different note, you've got a 2TB disk with MBR formatting... which is incorrect... it should be GPT.